# Fetch client redirect

Tags: javascript, fetch, aurelia

I'm executing a fetch request with the FetchClient (through an Aurelia wrapper).

The fetch client has three modes:

Follow, Error and Manual (I'll discard error for this question)

If I use follow, the fetch client automatically follows the redirection. The problem is that my original request uses basic auth. It works for the original request, but the redirected URL fails with those basic auth credentials.

If I use the "manual" mode, it doesn't follow through, but I don't get access to the "Location" of the redirected resource and I can't get the proper URL for the redirected resource.

How can I work around this?

It would either be a mode where I get access to the complete response, or an interceptor that allows me to modify the headers before requesting the redirected resource.

Comment: Why the close vote? it has obvious desired behavior (two possible desired behaviors). i can't post the code to the shortest behavior because it needs front-end code and two back-end services that exhibit the specific behavior

Comment: I guess the close vote (not from me) is because you don’t show any code nor show any error messages. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#atomic-http-redirect-handling: *“Redirects… are not exposed to APIs. Exposing redirects might leak information not otherwise available through a cross-site scripting attack.”* So there’s no way, from frontend JavaScript running in a browser, to trace redirects. That’s by design per the spec. There’s intentionally nothing exposed to frontend code that’d allow the code to access the redirect information. The browser transparently handles any redirects. That’s true no matter what redirect mode you set. Certainly you never want to use `redirect: manual`.

Comment: Yeah, I read the spec and came to that conclusion as well. It seems there is no workaround apart from modifying the back-end. It would work fine if the second service would just ignore the auth headers I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `url` property of the response when `redirected` property is `true`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url

```
fetch("someUrl")
.then(r=>{
  if(r.redirected){
     const redirectedToUrl = r.url
  }  
}
```